# ActionChains doesn't work, unless I manually refresh the selenium browser

Tags: selenium

I'm using selenium, and in the middle of the automation, this code only works if I manually refresh the browser.

If I do `driver.get("URL")`, or `driver.refresh()`, it doesn't help.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains   

elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div') 
elem = elems[3]

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click(elem)
action.send_keys("text")
action.perform()
```

I already can't use `elem.send_keys()`, it doesn't work anyway or anyhow. Though `elem.click()` does, that doesn't help if `elem.send_keys()` doesn't.

Comment: When it does not work then what is the error ?

Comment: There is no error, the Jupyter cell runs

Comment: hmmm.. try below solution and let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159). I get this error whether or not I manually refresh the page, with the below solution

Comment: You're targeting a <DIV>.  You should target the <INPUT>... then you can use sendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use explicit wait in this case like this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains   

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div') 
elem = elems[3]

action = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of((elem))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of((elem))).send_keys("text")
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Can you try `driver.refresh()` now with this code  ?

Comment: Can I have the webpage ?

Comment: I can't mention the webpage

Comment: okay, I understand can you give me the page resource  ??

Comment: the html, you mean?

Comment: I think there was a miscommunication, can you give me entire page resource ?

Comment: You need to save the source code into a text file, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free ofcourse). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236331/discussion-between-ipulatov-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: did you find an answer eventually?